# What is the closest equivalent to a for-loop in Racket-sdp?

Tags: loops, recursion, scheme, racket

Is recursion the only way to write something like a for-loop in the Racket dialect sdp ("Schreibe dein Programm!"), in which "(for)" isn't  a thing or is there a more "efficient" or simpler way to do so?

What would the closest equivalent to the C++ loop `for(i = 0 , i < 100, i++)`  look like in Racket-sdp code?

How I did this up until now was:

```racket
(: my-loop (natural -> %a))
(define my-loop
    (lambda (i)
        (cond
            [(< i 100) (my-loop (+ i 1))] ; <-- count up by one till 99 is reached
            [else "done"] ; <-- end
        )))

(my-loop 0)
```

EDIT:

It's more of a general question. If I were to write lets say a raket library which contains a general function, that might be used like this:

```racket
(for 0 (< i 100) (+ i 1) (func i))
```

in my programs which is a for-loop that runs with a given function as it's "body", would there be a way to implement this properly?

Comment: The closest thing to a `for` loop in Racket is ... a [`for`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) loop.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Sorry, I forgot to mention, that I am working with the educational dialect sdp ("Schreibe dein Programm!"), which is a requirement from my university (for whatever reason) for this project. I edited the question accordingly!

Comment: Is this a general question or are you trying to solve some specific problem? In some cases, you can replace recursion with functions such as `map`, `for-each`, `filter` or `fold` (and some sdp variants include these).

Comment: Your course is most likely expecting you to learn how to think recursively, not try to work your way around it and reach for your comfort zone. (You can add loops, and other control structures, with macros - procedures are not enough - but I don't think SdP has macros.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Professor of the mentioned course here.]

Recursion indeed is the only way to express iterated computation in the Racket dialect we are pursuing.  (Yes, that's by design.)

Still, higher-order functions (and recursion) provide all you need to create your own "loop-like control structures".  Take the following HOF, for example, which models a `repeat-until` loop:

```
(: until ((%a -> boolean) (%a -> %a) %a -> %a))
(define until
  (lambda (done? f x)
    (if (done? x)
        x
        (until done? f (f x)))))
```

Note that the `until` function is tail-recursive.  You can expect it to indeed behave like a loop at runtime — a clever compiler will even translate such a function using plain `jump` instructions.  (We'll discuss the above in the upcoming Chapter 12.)

Comment: Does this language include `do`? Still recursion under the hood, but closer to a C style for loop in organization.

Comment: It does not.  We're following the _Schreib Dein Programm_ dialect (very much inspired by HtDP): https://docs.racket-lang.org/deinprogramm/sdp-vanilla.html

Comment: @Shawn `do` isn't a primitive form in Scheme either. It is derived from a macro that solves it [using recursion](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r5rs-html/r5rs_9.html#SEC80)

Comment: @Sylwester *Still recursion under the hood*

Answer (score 2):

You can make a high-order for-loop.
Here is an simple example:

```
(define (for start end f)
  (define (loop i)
    (when (< i end)
      (f i)
      (loop (+ i 1))))
  (loop start))

(for 0 10 (λ (i) (displayln i)))
```

You can make this more general if you use a `next` function instead of `(+ i 1)` and use a `while-predicate?` function instead of `(< i end)`.